# Add new column with prior 7 transactions in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, count, window-functions

For customer segmentation, I need to analysis how many transactions did the customer do in prior 7 days, prior 14 days etc. basis a given transaction date. Copied the input and required output tables

I have tried using this but it seems the logic is incorrect

```
UPDATE WU5
SET txnLast7Days = subquery.txnLast7Days
FROM
    (       
        SELECT  Transaction_Date, sum(dateCounts.transactionCount) OVER (ORDER BY Transaction_Date RANGE BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as txnLast7Days
        FROM (SELECT count(*) transactionCount, Transaction_Date FROM WU5 GROUP BY Transaction_Date) as dateCounts
    ) subquery
WHERE WU5.Transaction_Date = subquery.Transaction_Date
```

[image: Input Table]

[image: Output Table]

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions and a range specification:

```
select w.*,
    count(*) over(
        partition by customer_id 
        order by transaction_date 
        range between interval 7 day preceding and interval 1 day preceding
    ) txnLast7Days,
    count(*) over(
        partition by customer_id 
        order by transaction_date 
        range between interval 14 day preceding and interval 1 day preceding
    ) txnLast14Days
from wu5 w
```

If you wanted an `update` statement:

```
update wu5 w
inner join (
    select transaction_id,
        count(*) over(
            partition by customer_id 
            order by transaction_date 
            range between interval 7 day preceding and interval 1 day preceding
        ) txnLast7Days,
        count(*) over(
            partition by customer_id 
            order by transaction_date 
            range between interval 14 day preceding and interval 1 day preceding
        ) txnLast14Days
    from wu5 w
) w1 on w1.transaction_id = w.transaction_id
set w.txnLast7Days = w1.txnLast7Days, w.txnLast14Days = w1.txnLast7Days
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...Just wanted to check as my table name is WU5 should I be using the below code. Sorry I am new to SQL coding

Comment: select WU5.*,
    count(*) over(
        partition by customer_id 
        order by transaction_date 
        range between interval 7 day preceding and interval 1 day preceding
    ) txnLast7Days,
    count(*) over(
        partition by customer_id 
        order by transaction_date 
        range between interval 14 day preceding and interval 1 day preceding
    ) txnLast14Days
from WU5

Comment: Is there also a way in MS SQL as interval function does not work there

Comment: @AMP: yes the query uses table name `wu5`, as in your question. It is *aliased* `w` (or `w1`) in the queries.

Comment: @AMP: why did you tag your question MySQL if you are running SQL Server? The two queries I provided will not run in MS SQL...